# Sociology dataset

Tags: discussion

I'm looking for sociology datasets, such as one in [this link](http://communication.iresearchnet.com/communication-and-social-change/social-networks/) (Fig. 1), which shows interactions between people, labeled based on their features, like age, race, or gender. It seems History stackexchange is the only place to post sociology questions. Is this the right place?

Comment: [scope](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) would be the first place to check. I thought that text discouraged asking about other social sciences, but it appears that I'm wrong.    If the dataset can be used in the study and practice of history, then I'd be inclined to admit it.  But "the only place to post sociology questions" is wrong; "If your question is not specifically on-topic for History Stack Exchange, it may be on topic for another Stack Exchange site. If no site currently exists that will accept your question, you may commit to or propose a new site at Area 51,"

Answer (score 1):

There isn't necessarily a "right place" to ask on the SE network for every question the human mind can dream up. So yes, that means there's nowhere to ask some questions, as much as a questioner might want there to be.

We do cover some questions about Sociology, Archeology, and Anthropology that heavily touch on history, but it does have to be a question about the past of humanity. For instance, my little sister is a professional Anthropologist who currently is studying how the Osage Nation is going about reasserting their national authority in the modern day. So while many Anthropology questions would be on topic here, almost no questions she is interested in answering would be.